# Reading Asset Xml File

Tags: java, android

I want to read an xml file placed in assets/ directory.
I've tried this solution (finded online)

```
InputStream istr = context.getAssets().open("stanza.xml");
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(); 
factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
XmlPullParser xrp = factory.newPullParser(); 
xrp.setInput(istr, "UTF-8");
```

but return me FileNotFoundException, but the file exists.

Please, help me to understand.

Comment: check if you have file named "stanza.xml" in your assets folder or if you have spelled right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your code is of your activity you can simply write:

```
InputStream istr =  getResources().getAssets().open("stanza.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
InputStream istr = context.getResources().getAssets().open("<FILE_PATH/YOUR_FILE_NAME>");
```

instead of

```
InputStream istr = context.getAssets().open("stanza.xml");
```

Comment: Return this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.axiomatic.librogame/it.axiomatic.librogame.pagina}: java.lang.NullPointerException